# Elements get inside each other

Tags: css, css-float, margin

I'm developing a simple css theme and i'm using left-center-right layout, I am using `float` for positioning the right and left elements, and `margin` for the center.
But if I take a look at the website, all the website parts are getting inside each other. 


Here is what I've got right now:

## HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="title">My Block Of Data Here Is Title</div>
            This is my block of data! Here i can show website stats and announcements.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="title">My Block Of Data Here Is Title</div>
            This is my block of data! Here i can show website stats and announcements.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="center">                
        <div class="block">
            <div class="title">Welcome to SITE_TITLE_HERE!</div>
            This is where we post so many stuff!<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Thanks, SITE_TITLE_HERE stuff.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 65%;
}   

.left{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}   

.right{
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
}

.center{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60%;
}

.block{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #fafafa;
    outline: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    outline-offset: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

.block .title{
    font-size: 24px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    background: #76E0EE;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/XK6dN/2/

Update: I'm almost sure it's the `outline` of the block class, but even if it's that. how can I keep them from overriding each other ?

Comment: Put your code here, in the question, but keep the link to the Fiddle.

Comment: @RobertHarvey + as well, the jsFiddle link is still extremely useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply because the widths of the elements don't add up.

The padding/borders are calculated in the width of the element, therefore:

`20%` + `20%` + `60%` + `6px` (padding) + `2px` (borders) **!=** `100%`.

You can change the box-model of an element to include the padding/border in its width calculation by using the property [**`box-sizing`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2sTJk/1/)

```
.block{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

There is still a problem though, as each element has an `outline` of `1px` on each side.

I suggest changing this to a `border`, thus solving the problem.

Alternatively, instead of using [**`box-sizing`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), you could use [**`calc()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to subtract the padding/borders from the elements widths.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/KVLEL/)

```
.left{
    float: left;
    width: calc(20% - 8px);
}   

.right{
    float: right;
    width: calc(20% - 8px);
}

.center{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: calc(60% - 8px);
}
```

Comment: also the OP has include an `outline` property that isn't included into `border-box` and the announcement word breaks the width because is too long

Comment: @Danko Thanks for pointing that out.. I couldn't even see it because it was so light.

Comment: @JoshC Thank you very much, I now understand my mistake and know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because for the child `.block` elements of each floated div as well as the centered one, you are declaring a 100% width (therefore inheriting parents' widths) **and** an additional 6px in width (3px left and right padding). This causes the content to overflow, as you are adding 6px on top of the 100% width.

To fix this, declare `box-sizing: border-box` on `.block`:

```
.block {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Makes magic happen */
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #fafafa;
    outline: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    outline-offset: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

It is not magic *per se*, but by using a [**border-box** box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), you are forcing the 100% width to include all possible decorations, including the outline, border and paddings, to be accounted for when calculating the final width.

http://jsfiddle.net/XK6dN/3/